# How to check content of zip folder before uploading?

Tags: php, codeigniter, backbone.js, zip

I have gone through the various post regarding zip and to read zip that is extracting zip downloading it and then access it. But i want to check the format and name convention for the files enclosed in Zip file that is going to be uploaded. I am using drag drop feature here and planning that when user drop the zip file it should extract the file but don't store it any where and check that all the image uploaded in the zip are of same format and name convention are followed like img1.jpg, img2.jpg.

Any help is deeply appreciated. I am using codeignitor framework and is it possible to extract and manipulate zip using backbone or java script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think you can check the contents of the zip before uploading.. Here's a code , you can very well use to check if the content inside is legit. [In this example... Assuming **`img1.zip`** contains an image file **`img1.jpg`**]

Maybe a start

```
<?php
$zip = new ZipArchive;
$res = $zip->open('img1.zip');
if ($res) {
    $legitImage=explode('.',$zip->statIndex(0)['name']);
    if($legitImage[1]=='jpg')
    {
        echo "It's an image";
        //do your operations
        $zip->close();
    }
    else
    {
        unlink('img1.zip');//Delete the zip file since it does not contain image
    }


}
?>
```

Comment: hi. shankar do we need to use some libraries or something coz this code is not showing any results I use PHP 5 >

Comment: I tried it but its showing Warning: ZipArchive::statIndex() [ziparchive.statindex]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/ecrafts/public_html/zip.php on line 5

Warning: ZipArchive::close() [ziparchive.close]: Invalid or unitialized Zip object in /home/ecrafts/public_html/zip.php on line 6 errors.

Comment: zip.php is not a zip file, its a PHP file. Give a proper zip file to the open function.

Comment: Hi shankar i got that working but can u suggest that can i directly access the zip file via web link. Is there any way to do so. Am finding the same but didnt got any.